# JS & React- forEach and For Loop only giving one result, when I console.log the array, it shows multiple items avaialbe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook

I am using axios to call an api to retreive pictures when a button is hit.  The problem I am having is I get errors when I use photos.forEach saying forEach is not a function. Currently using the for loop it only displays the first result. When I console.log the array is full of the photos I'm just having difficulty accessing them! Im sure this is simple, I am currently learning js and react and need some guidance. Thanks!

```js
function Facebook() {
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState('');
    const getData = () => {
        axios
            .request(options)
            .then(function (response) {
                const data = response.data.photos.data;
                setPhotos(
                    data.map((image) => {
                        return image.picture;
                    }),
                );
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    //console.log(photos.length);
    //console.table(photos);

    const photoList = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
            console.table(photos);
            return <img className='img image-full' src={photos[i]} />;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={getData}
                className='inline-block px-4 py-3 text-sm font-semibold text-center text-white uppercase transition duration-200 ease-in-out bg-indigo-500 rounded-md cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-600'>
                Tailwind Button
            </button>
            <div className='flex flex-row mx-auto'>
                <ul>
                    <li>{photoList()}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Facebook;
```

[Console.log for photosArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FEmb.png)

Comment: if photos.forEach is not a function, what type is "photos" of? should be a map-object but isnt? what if you try `for(photo in photos)`?

Comment: Your initial sate of `photos` is an empty string, while eventually it becomes an array. You need to `useState([])`, otherwise you'll have problems when `getData` have not been called yet.

Comment: Thank you, setting useState to useState([]) helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either initialize photos with an empty array, or just leave it undefined and check if it is set when you access it later. I would rather just use an empty array though:

```
function Facebook() {
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
    ...
```

Btw, you can also use map for getting the photos in JSX and omit the photoList function, but that is just a matter of opinion:

```
return (
    <div>
        <button
            onClick={getData}
            className='inline-block px-4 py-3 text-sm font-semibold text-center text-white uppercase transition duration-200 ease-in-out bg-indigo-500 rounded-md cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-600'>
            Tailwind Button
        </button>
        <div className='flex flex-row mx-auto'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {photos.map((elem) => {
                        return <img className='img image-full' src={elem} />;
                    })}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and looping straight on the page vs in a function worked out much better!